# Form-data in API Connect

Tags: apiconnect

How do I get request form-data as a string in API Connect? I tried to get it in Gateway script by different ways, like `apim.getvariable('request.body')` or `session.input.readAsBuffer`, but everything was unsuccessful. I have two attachments in form-data and I would like to split it in my script.

At the moment I haven't found any documentation about processing form-data in IBM API Connect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a POST QueryString you can decode the URI component in your Gateway script using:

```
var myQueryString = decodeURIComponent(apim.getvariable('request.body').item(0).toBuffer().toString())
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm using POST request, but my data is located in formData, not in query string of URI. Here is description of my service:

paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: file
          in: formData
          description: File to upload
          required: false
          type: file

Comment: Can you encode your Data as JSON then send it to API Connect?

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it.